# Why animation doesn't work in an Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to develop the first animation in an Angular 5 app and it doesn't work.
What I've done till now in detail:

1. app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ...
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ...
```

In my component:

```
import { trigger,style,transition,animate,keyframes,query,stagger } from '@angular/animations';

animations: [

      trigger('slideOut', [
          transition('* => void', [
            style({height: '*'}),
            animate('2000ms ease-out', style({height: 0})),
          ])
        ])

    ]
```

Here is the template:

```
 <div [@slideOut] class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    All is good!
</div>
```

Any idea what I'm missing here ? Do I need to install something?

Comment: is there `NoopAnimationModule` in the app.module.ts?

Comment: There is no NoopAnimationModule

Comment: I think you can find more details [here](https://youtu.be/oa9cnWTpqP8)

Comment: I think I've seen this video before, actually I've seen more than this including video on animation specifically.

Comment: Check the console for error or might be you have missed any single step?

Comment: The console is open , no errors